# IBM Worklight 6.2 Cannot set status. Response already committed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, worklight-runtime

**Environment:**

IBM Worklight Server 6.2

IBM Liberty profile 8.5.5.1

IBM DB2

Windows 2008 Standard Edition

Whenever a request from Worklight server to Backend, following warning logged in server console.

```
[10/7/14 1:40:39:192 PDT] 00000056 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt W WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[10/7/14 1:40:47:973 PDT] 00000056 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt W WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
[10/7/14 1:40:57:710 PDT] 00000051 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt W WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
```

Read this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081989/worklight-uncaught-typeerror-for-multiple-javascript) but in my case the application receives data and it works fine.

Can this be ignored since it is warning or a solution is available to solve this?

Comment: Could you describe in detail the scenario when this happens?

Comment: @PavelLeonov, I couldn't find the scenario exactly. But Whenever app calls adapter I can find the log.

Comment: @Karikalan, can you verify that this is happening (or not...) in the very latest iFix for 6.2.0.01?

Answer (score 0):

This warning message can be ignored. It is harmless.
Still, I have opened an internal defect to track it and make sure it will not display anymore.

There is no manual workaround.
If this is important enough for you, you can also open a PMR to receive a fix when available.

Additionally, it'd be great if you could elaborate on when exactly this is happening.